# How to pass data from one gridview in other gridview

Tags: asp.net

I have a gridview, it has 8 cells. One cell has a textbox when double click on the textbox, a popup will be opened. How to pass the popup value to second gridview? Please give me solution.

Comment: if u have any code, please send it

Comment: provide your code so we can guide you.

Answer (score 0):

HTML Markup
In the following HTML Markup there’s an Asp.Net GridView control with a Button to select the row. Also I have added a Button which will send the Asp.Net GridView Selected Row to the other page when clicked.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Font-Names="Arial"
Font-Size="10pt">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="CustomerID" HeaderText="CustomerID" />
    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="PostalCode" HeaderText="PostalCode" />
    <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSelect" runat="server" Text="Select" CommandName = "Select" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:Button ID="btnSend" runat="server" Text="Send Selected Row" OnClick = "Send" />
```

Passing the Selected Row to the other page
When the send button is clicked it first checks whether the GridView Row has a Selected Row or not. If the GridView has a Selected Row it does a Server.Transfer to the Page2.aspx. I am doing Server.Transfer instead of Response.Redirect since with Server.Transfer we can reference the previous page and its controls. And if the user has not selected any row in the ASP.Net GridView we ask him to select one using a JavaScript alert.
Finally on Page2.aspx the data from the cells of the Selected Row of the ASP.Net GridView is displayed.

C#

```
protected void Send(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (GridView1.SelectedRow != null)
    {
        Server.Transfer("~/Page2.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Please select a row.')", true);
    }
}
```

Now on Page2.aspx we fetch the ASP.Net GridView SelectedRow in the following way

C#

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Page.PreviousPage != null)
    {
        GridView GridView1 = (GridView)this.Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("GridView1");
        GridViewRow selectedRow = GridView1.SelectedRow;
        Response.Write("CustomerId: " + selectedRow.Cells[0].Text + "<br />");
        Response.Write("City: " + selectedRow.Cells[1].Text + "<br />");
        Response.Write("PostalCode: " + selectedRow.Cells[2].Text);
    }
}
```

Link:
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Pass-Selected-Row-of-ASPNet-GridView-control-to-another-Page.aspx